# mspdbsrv.exe living forever?

Tags: visual-studio

Is there a way to prevent mspdbsrv.exe from continuing to run
after finishing the compilation? or even after I terminate visual studio? or perhaps even prevent it from even spawning in the first place?

what is this guy good for anyway?

using vs2005

Comment: I've seen this now in VS2008 Pro

Comment: I can see this problem with the VS2012 (express edition).

Comment: Running VS2013 and the mspdbsrv.exe zombies are still walking around, causing builds to fail.

Comment: Seen just now on VS 2017 RC

Comment: Seen it now in VS2019

Comment: And again in VS2019 too, quite frequently actually (already hit 4 times by it today)

Answer (score 21):

MS recommends to add a postbuild-event to the Project options [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/ravi_kumar/archive/2009/06/17/my-2-cents-on-mspdbsrv-exe.aspx).

> [...]Sometimes it is possible that
>   mspdbsrv.exe stays alive even after
>   the build is over. In such scenarios,
>   it is safe to add a post build event
>   to kill the mspdbsrv.exe.

Background infos on postbuild-Events can be found on the [linked](http://blogs.msdn.com/ravi_kumar/archive/2009/06/17/my-2-cents-on-mspdbsrv-exe.aspx) page.

Answer (score 12):

mspdbsrv.exe is the process Visual Studio uses to create .pdb files when you compile; these are the symbol files that let you debug an application.  Sometimes it goes berserk and doesn't shutdown correctly when you exit Visual Studio.  I've had this cause bad compiles even after quitting and restarting Visual Studio.  Use [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653) or the task list (Ctrl+Alt+Delete in Windows) to manually kill mspdbsrv.exe if it's broken on you.

For what it's worth, I haven't seen this problem happen in Visual Studio 2008 as of yet, but I've only been using it a few days.

Comment: Faster task list shortcut: Ctrl + Shift + Esc

Comment: In my case the msdbgsrv.exe process(es) didn't even show up in Task Manager.  Using Process Explorer I did find them; they were parented under totally random other processes (once under FireFox, once under some background Adobe Creative Cloud process).  Using taskkill I could get rid of them nonetheless.

Answer (score 3):

A little googling seems to indicate that mspdbsrv.exe zombies are a known issue in VS2005. We've had similar (intermittent) problems, but there did not seem to be a solution.

Yes, it sucks.

Comment: `taskkill /im mspdbsrv.exe`

Comment: @ErikAronesty: ; in my case I had to do a `taskkill /f /t /im mspdbsrv.exe ` (force-kill).  But useful to have in a .cmd file or under a Tools menu shortcut indeed!